# Leibniz formula for determinants and the sign function

Tags: permutations, determinant, parity

I'm trying to build up an intuition for the Leibniz formula for matrix determinants. I understand that it relies on the *sign* or *signature* function of permutations, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation).

What I don't understand about this is, is there a meaning or significance to this sign function? I mean, just because a permutation involves an odd number of transpositions, why does that make it inherently *negative*?

Is this just a convention we adopt because it happens to make determinants come out correctly, or is there a more general meaning to it?

Comment: It is a convention. But think that if you apply twice the same transposition, they cancel each other. Hence an even number should correspond to $+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a convention based on the usual definition of a cross product in $3-D$ space that is referred to a [right-handed ordered basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)). This convention gives a positive sign to the volume of a cube whose sides are oriented as a right-handed basis.

Changing the convention simply change the sign of the determinant. And the determinant is the signed volume of the $n-$dimensional parallelepiped spanned by the column or row vectors of the matrix.

Comment: You should not limit the discussion to the 3D case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. The 3D case is the intuitively simpler and the higher dimension case is its natural extension.